# SignalR Replaces Message Queue

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, signalr, message-queue

Does SignalR replaces MSMQ or IMB MQ or Tibco message queues.

I have gone through SignalR.StockTicker

If we extend the functionality to read Stock tickers from multiple data sources and display to UI, will lit replaces usage of Message Queue

Answer (score 26, accepted):

SignalR is designed for real-time messaging using several protocols (WebSockets, Long Polling, Server Sent Events, or Forever Frame).  On the other hand, Service Bus type protocols (Such as MSMQ, RabbitMQ, Azure Service Bus) are designed for decoupled communication.  The use cases can overlap,  but in general, if you're looking for real-time updates (chat, tickers, notifications of a user status change) then SignalR is a good solution.  One key difference is that MSMQ and the like do not require that the recipients, or subscribers, be online at the time the message is sent, whereas a SignalR client must be listening or it will miss the notification.

HTH